# How can I iterate through items I've selected with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a group of divs like this:

```
<div>Div 1</div>
<div>Div 2</div>
<div>Div 3</div>
<div>Div 4</div>
<div>Div 5</div>
```

How can I loop through these using jquery? Is it possible to make an array out of this? Maybe something like this:

```
var divArray = $('div');

foreach(var div in divArray)
{
    if( divArray[0] = "Div 3")
        //do stuff
}
```

I don't want to apply any classes or id's because I'm actually using some jqplot charts which I'm unable to modify. However, the principle is the same as in my simple example above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)**:

```
$('div').each(function() {
    if($.trim($(this).text()) == "Div 3") {
        //do stuff
    } 
});
```